# ReactJS: Issue with accessing event.target children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

I have within my React App a component containing an element with an onMouseEnter/Leave handler

```
<CollapseElement>
  <li onMouseEnter={e => handleEnter(e)}>
   {props.children}
  </li>
</CollapseElement>
```

The li is passed children through props, amongst which an element with a className of "targetelement" that I would like to access within the handleEnter of CollpaseElement component and pass it to a function

```
const handleEnter = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e.currentTarget.innerHTML)
        function(...)
    }
```

While the console.log does show me the innerHTML amongst which the target, I cannot figure a way of selecting it. I have tried querySelector('.targetelement'), closest or querySelectorAll to no success: either a null error or, for example if the function is trying to get the coordinates of the target element, I end up with all values at 0

Thank you for your input

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? you shouldn't have to use dom api directly in your react code

Comment: @tudor.gergely I want to get the size of the element to dynamically update the coordinates of another element, and the function being called is provided through context + hooks

Comment: Have you investigated whether [React refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) would be useful to you in this case?

Comment: @ThomasUpton it was next on my list, but since the official documentation mentions they should be used carefully and not too often and since I have never used them so far, I preferred seeing first what more experienced users would suggest before digging into maybe a not so recommended way of doing this. I will contine investigating it in parellel though while awaiting answers here

Comment: refs not solving the issue. Also because the element targeted depends on the mouseEnter event, so if I understood refs correctly I would need to add a ref to each different possible targeted element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. The issue was in understanding the sync and rendering of React/DOM elements. By using useEffect in the parent element with the correct event sent via the context, I am able to target the child with the class I needed

Comment: Would you by any chance still have this solution code and share it?